# Trying to get property of non-object [Laravel] when trying to access Auth::user()->name on view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get username from view using:

`Auth::user()->name`

and I'm getting

`Trying to get property of non-object`

because `Auth::user()` is NULL. How is this possible? The navbar laravel generates uses the same and it works there.

EDIT: It seems that I can't even get the auth user from the Controller.

```
Auth::guard('admin')->check(); //true
Auth::user(); //null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your missing `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: But where do I put that? Because I want to access it from a view not a controller.

Comment: If the user is logged in you can get it from the \Request `public function yourmethod(Request $request)` then `$request->user()`

Comment: all use statements go at the top of the file, in every file you use the namespace.

Comment: Or you could make it ugly and do `echo \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->name` ;p

Comment: Its all in the docs, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

Comment: Check my edit..

Answer (score 4):

Well I figured it out again, since I used a custom guard, I actually needed to use:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use global `auth()` from view.

```
{{auth()->user()->name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are logged in before trying to access a view with `{{Auth::user()->name}}`.